# Downloading a directory through FTP on Android using Apache Commons FTP library

Tags: java, android, apache-commons, ftp-client

My FTP server has 1500 files in 600 directories, I have to download the entire structure as it is, to the Android phone; recursive download takes a lot of time. Is there any library which downloads the directories.

Comment: getting a complete directory is not an FTP function. one way or another, you need to go through all the directories and list the content. One question would be: do you really need all these files? Can you zip the structure, download it and unzip it on the phone?

Comment: Just did that! It works Blazingly fast! 15 mins to 4 mins!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a Zip file did save me 15 min!!!